# Saving Dynamic Values in Database Using Loop

Tags: vb.net

Hello I have a code that creates dynamic textbox and datetimepicker in vb and then I want to save it in my database but my problem is my code saves data more than my dynamic created items. I know that this is happening because my code is inside the 2 loop but i dont know how to remove it from the 2 loops. Please help me thanks.

my code is here:

```
 For Each textbox As TextBox In panelGroupDependent.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()              
        For Each dtp In panelGroupDependent.Controls.OfType(Of DateTimePicker)()
               SaveRecord("INSERT INTO `tbl name`(`value1`, `value2`, `value3`) VALUES ('" & txt1.Text & "','" & textbox.Text & "','" & dtp.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "')")
        Next   
 Next
                MsgBox("Dependents Records Added Successfully", , "Dependents Records")
```

Comment: Please use parameters to avoid SQL injection! If you have more than 1 TextBox and/or more than 1 DateTimePicker, your For Each loops are executed every time. Check `panelGroupDependent` for such controls.

Comment: what do you mean? if i use the check panelGroupDependent my data will be saved properly unlike what im doing?

Comment: Aren't the number of your textboxes and datetimepicker equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your Textboxes and Datetimepickers with the following convention:

1. `Textbox1`, `Textbox2`, `Textbox3`...
2. `DateTimePicker1`, `DateTimePicker2`, `DateTimePicker3`...

Then you can use a code like the following:

```
for i = 1 to Me.panelGroupDependent.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Count()
    Dim txtBox As TextBox  = CType(Me.Controls("Textbox" & i),TextBox)
    Dim dtPicker As DateTimePicker = CType(Me.Controls("DateTimePicker"&i),DateTimePicker)
    SaveRecord("INSERT INTO `tablename`(`value1`, `textbox`, `datetimepicker`) VALUES ('" & txtEmpNumber.Text & "','" & txtBox.Text & "','" & dtPicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "')")
Next
```